# ChromeDriverManager() with splinter and bs4 - a sustainable solution

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using ChromeDriverManager() with splinter and bs4 to complete webscraping tasks.

The latest changes to ChromeDriverManager() are proving difficult for me to work around.

What is everyone else doing to work around this? What's a long term sustainable solution?

Here's my current code for opening Chrome and navigating to the first URL.

Python 3.10.7
Chrome Version 116.0.5845.111 (Official Build) (64-bit)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from splinter import Browser
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

executable_path = {'executable_path': ChromeDriverManager().install()}
browser = Browser('chrome', **executable_path, headless=False)
browser.visit(library_url)
```

So far I've tried:

```
executable_path = {'executable_path': ChromeDriverManager(version="114.0.5735.90").install()}
```

But this stopped working once Chrome went to version 116.

I've also downloaded the zip from https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/ but not sure how to utilize.